# Automatically add last post to a carousel/slider

Tags: slideshow

Is there a carousel (or slider) plugin out there that allows me to add the most recent post to be an item on the carousel?

The website has a custom post type of `garden_update` and there will be a new `garden_update` post created roughly every week. The site has a carousel on the homepage with a few items, but one of them must be the most recent `garden_update` post.

Is there an existing plugin that allows this? Or do I need to create my own plugin for something like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will probably get you going.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-posts-carousel/

Maybe a custom slider, like jQuery Light Slider, it very much depends on how much you want to customise it :)